# How to inject singleton class in another class with constructor parameters in scala and create it's objects just the constructor?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I have a singleton class:

```
@Singleton
class Inject_Class_A @Inject()(
                            wsClient: WSClient,
                          )(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {
// ... does something

}
```

I have another main class in which I want to inject the previous class, it also have other construct parameters. IDE says it is syntactically correct:

```
class Main_Class @Inject()(
                           inject_class_A: Inject_Class_A,
                           implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext
                           )(key: String, value: String) {

// ... does something different using inject_class_A
}
```

Now I want to create objects as:

```
val main_class = new Main_Class(key: "KEY", value:"VALUE")
```

Ofcourse it gives error:

```
Unspecified value parameters: inject_class_A: Inject_Class_A, executionContext: ExecutionContext
```

I tried this way also:

```
class Main_Class(key: String, value: String) {

  @Inject val inject_class_A: Inject_Class_A = new Inject_Class_A()

// ... does something different using inject_class_A
}
```

But this doesn't work as I don't have `wsClient: WSClient` and `executionContext: ExecutionContext`
and these I get only from injection only.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by manually instantiating the `Main_Class`? Is this in a test context?

Comment: Nope. You can imagine it as there are several accounts, and each has its own keys, say apiKey. This key is used in the `Inject_Class_A` functions and in the `Main_Class` functions as well.
Now I want to create a single `Main_Class` object for each account. The function of `Inject_Class_A` is common for each account, and it needs to have `wsClient` and `executionContext` which is only received via `@Injection` in `Play`.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible or not but since the `Main_Class` definition is syntactically correct, I am hoping it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With standard Guice, you can *either* have a class injected *or* instantiate it yourself. Not both at the same time. You could inject into an existing instance, but that's ugly. If you need an injected instance with runtime-determined parameters, you should look into [Assited injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

Answer (score 0):

*It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve with this pattern, thus my answer may not fit your use case.*

One option could be to use a "wrapper" class:

```scala
// No automatic injection for this class
// Move implicit parameter at the end for ease of instantiation 
class Main_Class (inject_class_A: Inject_Class_A)
                 (key: String, value: String)
                 (implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext) {
}

@Singleton
class Wrapper @Inject()(inject_class_A: Inject_Class_A)
                       (implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

  // Manual instantiation of Main_Class
  // Implicit automatically passed
  val main1 = new Main_Class(inject_class_A)("key", "value")

}
```

Comment: This seems to be one way of doing so. But not in the neatest way. Having extra `Wrapper` class, but thanks for this idea.